# Howto Wordpress + Ajax + Custom Post Type + Custom Metabox + Contact Form 7

Tags: ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7, meta-boxes

here's the situation:

I have a page generated from a custom post type in Wordpress.
This page has a custom metabox with a "thank you" message.
In this page there is a contact form generated with Contact Form 7.

What I would like to archive is that when someone submits the post, a ajax function replaces the form with the content in the metabox.

Now the content in the metabox has also some script (tracking codes) that I don't want to load before the the form is submitted.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you want but since you are using CF7 it requires quite a lot of customisation.

It would be way easier to achieve the desired result if you could hardcode the php form into the page.

Let me know if that's an option for you and maybe I can give you an hand.